# can't kill PID from script loop

Tags: bash, shell

I need a function for a script that gets pid for clipit (clipboard manager) and kills clipit. Pretty straightforward stuff I think except for some reason the shell is puking back an error about killing the PID. Here's my function:

```
stat=0
while [[ "$stat" == 0 ]] ; do
    clipitPid=$(ps aux|egrep -m 1 "[ \t]{1,}[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}[ \t]*clipit$"|sed -r "s/^[^ ]*[ ]*([0-9]{3,5})[ \t]{1,}.*$/\1/") #; echo "\$clipitPid: ${clipitPid}"
    kill "$clipitPid" 0>/dev/null 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    stat="$?"
done
```

and here is the terminal error:

```
10:12 ~ $ stat=0 ; while [[ "$stat" == 0 ]] ; do clipitPid=$(ps aux|egrep "[ \t]{1,}[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}[ \t]*clipit$"|sed -r "s/^[^ ]*[ ]*([0-9]{3,5})[ \t]{1,}.*$/\1/") ; echo "\$clipitPid: ${clipitPid}" ; kill "$clipitPid" 0>/dev/null 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; stat="$?" ; done
$clipitPid: 24760
24791
bash: kill: 24760
24791: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

I've tried removing the sending output to null and that makes no difference.
I have two instances of clipit running to ensure both PIDs are detected and killed; however, the PIDs are echoed ok but not being nuked. But if I manually 'kill 24760 24791' the PIDs are killed:

```
10:12 ~ $ kill 24760 24791
10:12 ~ $ ps aux|grep clipit
[3]-  Terminated              clipit
[4]+  Terminated              clipit
```

Any ideas what I have wrong here I would appreciate reading them.

**EDIT**

actually if I have only one instance of clipit running then it gets killed using the above onliner fine. 2 clipits or more then it fails to kill any, yet retrieves the PIDs ok.

Comment: if `pkill` is available why not use it? What O/S are you running on? If not you can still simplify your code. `clipitPid=$(ps -o pid,comm|grep clipit|grep -v grep|cut -d' ' -f1)`

Comment: @alvits: running Debian stable. Yeap pkill seems to work. I never have had much need for pkill I guess. I thought it might kill all processes that had clipit in their description like 'man clipit' but indeed it only kills the running instances of clipit when run and not the man page I opened to test. I've had horrible luck with 'cut' command in the past and simply prefer 'sed'. Maybe b/c I prefer 'sed' I've experienced probs with 'cut' command :)

Comment: but it is still curious why my superfluous function still wouldn't handle killing more than a single instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. If `pkill` is available use it.

`pkill -f clipit`

If not you can use something like.

`kill $(ps -eo pid,comm|grep clipit|grep -v grep|cut -d' ' -f1)`

Comment: you could also do something like this: `kill "$(pgrep -f 'clipit')"`, but peeps should never have a reason to do something obfusticated like: `kill "$(ps ... | grep ... | awk ... | more stuff ...)"`.  Both `ps` and `pgrep` are provided by the same package in (at least Debian-based) most Linuxes: `procps`.

Comment: `pgrep` and `pkill` are available in most Linux and Solaris. In most cases when `pkill` isn't available, neither is `pgrep`.

Comment: that's because both `pkill` and `pgrep` are provided by `procps`.

Comment: This too has the `grep -v grep` antipattern which riddles many of the poor reinventions of `pkill` which we don't seem to be able to prevent people from posting here multiple times a week.

Comment: @tripleee - I do agree with you completely. But I do believe most people also know that `grep clipit | grep -v grep` can be simplified to `awk '/clipit/'`. And furthermore `grep clipit | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f1` can be simplified to `awk '/clipit/ {print $1}'`. If you do see antipatterns in any answer, including this one, I encourage you to post a better answer. Your answers will be very helpful to the community and possibly help people avoid antipatterns in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those uncommon cases where you should *not* quote a parameter expansion.

The issue is that when you have two or more clipits, you end up setting `clipitPid` to a multiline string. When you then call `kill "$clipitPid"`, the quotes ensure that the entire value of `$clipitPid` are given to `kill` as a single argument. Since `kill` only accepts process or job IDs, and the two-line string "24760\n24791" is not a process or job ID, `kill` complains.

Had you written `kill $clipitPid`, then `bash` would have word-split the value of `$clipitPid` and provided the separate words as separate arguments to `kill`, which would have made `kill` happy.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you just do this in your function? Try it and see if it makes any difference

```
ps aux | grep clipit | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and a [useless use of `kill -9`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill) but pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

I can't at first look decipher your rather complex egrep, but if you're trying to kill a certain process id, what about:

```
kill `ps ax | fgrep clipit | fgrep -v fgrep | awk '{ print $1 }'`
```

Awk is one of the ancient AT&T Unix commands, but can come in handy when you need to pick a column out of a list.